# Как установить роль пользователю в Java EE?

Tags: java, java-ee, role

При логине пользователя я хочу установить ему роль на время сессии. Как это можно сделать?

Например, в одном из туториалов написано что "вы можете устанавливать роли через REALM бд, через LDAP, или создавать их на лету". Меня интересует именно создание роли на лету, есть что-нибудь типа такого?

```
session.getUser.setRole("usual-user")
```

И потом если на REST-методе стоит `@RolesAllowed("other-user")` то пользователь не сможет вызвать этот метод.

Если нет, то какие альтернативные [легкие] способы для создания ролей существуют?

UPD: Я читал, что роли можно установить на сервере. Но я так понимаю это роли именно для пользователей сервера? По крайне мере у меня

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поясню что я хочу сделать - я хочу чтобы незалогиненный пользователь не мог вызывать определенные службы. Я хочу сделать это красиво(по возможности не костыльным способом, без проверок во всяких фильтрах и перехватчиках и т.п.).

Я предполагал что это можно сделать так:
1) Определить роль для службы, т.е. ттолько пользователи с определенной ролью могут вызывать ее. Желательно с помощью аннотации.
2) Установить роль для пользователя при логине

Comment: При логине пользователя Вы не устанавливаете ему никакую роль. Если такой пользователь уже есть в базе, у него уже должна быть роль, то есть роль необходимо назначать при регистрации/создании пользователя.

Comment: @notaProgrammer хорошо. Как тогда сделать так чтобы пользователь не мог заходить на страницы и вызывать некоторые REST-службы если он не залогинен?

Я предполагал сделать так - когда пользователь логинится, ему присваивается роль. На службах стоят аннотации, которые проверяют определенные роли. Если у пользователя неподходящая роль, то он не сможет вызвать службу. Как и пользователь без роли тоже не сможет вызвать службу. Получается, так сделать нельзя. Тогда есть другой способ сделать все красиво(например, как с аннотациями)?

Comment: Это уже зависит от того, какие технологии Вы используете для разработки REST-сервисов.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/security-javaee002.htm#BNBYL

Comment: @notaProgrammer у вас написано в основном как проверять роли. А мне нужно узнать как установить роль. Ну или [как сделать службу логина нормально](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1001713/Как-правильно-сделать-авторизацию-в-java-ee-rest-проекте).