# Как правильно сделать авторизацию в Java EE REST проекте?

Tags: java, java-ee, rest, безопасность

У меня есть (учебное) REST приложение. На фронте ванильный JS. Взаимодействие между ними происходит через HTTP запросы.

Мне нужно сделать что-то наподобие службы логина. Т.е. чтобы незалогиненные пользователи не могли вызывать разные службы и заходить на разные страницы.

Сначала я хотел использовать аннотации безопасности на службах - `@RolesAllowed` и т.п.
Я думал что при логине можно просто установить пользователю роль (например так - `session.getPrincipal().setRole()`), и аннотации будут проверять роли, но так сделать нельзя(надо как то настраивать сервер, и т.п.).

Вариант 2 - сохранять токен (под "токен" я имею ввиду обычную `String` строку) в куки(с временем жизни) и в бд. Далее - написать аннотацию валидации, которая сверяет токен из куки и из бд, и понаставить эту аннотацию к службам.

Вариант 3 - сохранять роль в сессию(`session.setAttribute("role", Roles.USER)`), и аналогично написать аннотацию валидации.

Какой из этих вариантов более рабочий, более хороший? Какие у них недостатки? Может их можно как-то улучшить?

Отдельный вопрос - недостпуность страниц для пользователей. Как это правильно сделать? Пока только так:

Перед "рендерингом" страницы из JS посылается запрос в службу, которая проверяет роль или токен пользователя. Если у него нет достаточных прав, то страница не отрисовывается. Но он кажется мне плохим.

Comment: Почему кажется плохим то? это нормальная практика. Фронт сам по себе, бэк сам по себе. Фронт реагирует на то что ему сказал бэк. если бэк говорит нельзя, то фронт отображает что нельзя.

Comment: @Tsyklop не знаю, мне казалось что когда много запросов это плохо. Да и к тому же если js отключен то все равно фронт отрисуется? Правда работать не будет, я же запросы через js посылаю.

Comment: Если js отключен фронт вообще не должен что либо делать, окромя как сказать что js отключен и для дальнейшей работы его нужно включить.